# Делаю авторизацию на сайте django через steam, но получаю ошибку

Tags: django, авторизация, steam

Реализую авторизацию через steam, вот модель пользователя:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
id64 = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    'auth.Group',
    related_name='customuser_set',
    blank=True,
    verbose_name='groups',
    help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
)
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    'auth.Permission',
    related_name='customuser_set',
    blank=True,
    verbose_name='user permissions',
    help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id64
```

views:

```
class CustomUserAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, id64, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id64=id64)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    return user


def login_callback(request):
steam_uid = int(get_uid(request.GET))
if steam_uid is None:

    return render(request, "success.html", {'res':'ошибка'})
else:
    user = CustomUserAuthenticationBackend.authenticate(request, steam_uid)
    if user:
        login(request)
    else:
        CustomUser.objects.create(id64=steam_uid')
        user = CustomUserAuthenticationBackend.authenticate(request, steam_uid)
        login(request)

    return render(request, "success.html", {'res':steam_uid})
```

Получаю ошибку: CustomUserAuthenticationBackend.authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id64',         user = CustomUserAuthenticationBackend.authenticate(request, steam_uid)

Толкните пожалуйста в сторону решения, буду очень благодарен!